# MSExchange Receiver Rule

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007

First of all - unfortunately I am not an expert concerning msexchange.

I would like to know if it is possible to define a rule where the receiver of an outgoing email is changed automatically.

In Detail this is what I need:

If someone is sending an email to `my@example.com` with a subject containing e.g. `[TRACK]` we do want to send the email to another receiver instead of the original one e.g. `track@example.com`. It is important that the exchange server does not send an email to the initial receiver.

If this is not possible by checking the subject I would like to know if there is any other way to do this? For example by using suffixes in the domain `my@example.track.com`or something like this.

The purpose is that initially we wanted to send those emails to a specific server instead of sending the email at all. The server would then do some work with this email by extracting properties and saving them in a `mysql database`. Unfortunately I was told that it's not possible to tell an msexchange server to connect to another server via `SMTP` and forward an email etc. like described above.

That's why I am asking to do it via another postbox catching all the emails with a specific subject.

**EDIT**

Let me give you a little more background. We do have an `iOS app` for our consulting firm. With this app you are able to send `Messages` to one of our consulters. So the iPad user wirtes a message from his iPad and this message will be delivered as an `E-Mail` (mapped serverside).

For the reason that consulters do not need any third-party tools, we'd like them to use their email client to answer those emails or start new conversations with the iPad user. So that's why we need to deliver some of the emails (not every user is an iPad user) from the exchange server to our message server via (at best) smtp.

It is fairly important that the emails for the iPad users are not deliverd via email itself, but a message to the iPad.

Any hints appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: it is VERY hard to determine the "what?" and "why?" of this question. I am sure there are already e-mail discovery applications out there that might do whatever it is you are asking without modifying e-mail headers to dynamically reroute/copy e-mail, but again, it is hard to decipher your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did update the question to give you a little more background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna give an explanation on how I solved this problem.

First of all you have to define a `SendConnector` for a specific Domain. 
Let's say we define this connector for the Domain `*internal.server.de`
This will cause our new `SendConnector` to send all E-Mails with the above Domain being set as receiver.

Now we are facing the problem, that you cannot change `SendConnectors` dynamically on transport rule layer directly. But you can use a Workaround. It is possible to define a rule changing the sender of an email (`redirect`) to the Domain matching our `SendConnector`. 
So defining a rule which specifies that all E-Mails with a subject containing a specific Textphrase are getting redirected to the domain matching our `SendConnector`

This will indeed cause our `SendConnector`to be used dynamically depending on the subject.